# Xamarin Android take a photo with an intent without the Retry OK

Tags: android, xamarin, camera

I'd like to take a photo from Xamarin Android (not Forms) and have it take the shot, and return the photo, skipping the Retry and OK links at the bottom of the screen.

I'm not using any special library, just passing an intent as shown here:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/camera-application-create/

Here's my code to call the camera and the returned code:

```
        private void BtnCamera_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

       protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");

            AddPicturesToList(bitmap); // This adds the photo to a scrollable list
        }
```

I have seen elsewhere  you can do this but Xamarin is giving me an error the REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE does not exist in the current context.

```
        private void BtnCamera_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            intent.PutExtra("android.intent.extra.quickCapture", true);
            StartActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE); // <<<< Not working
        }
```

Is there anything wrong with doing it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StartActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`

the second parameter is an int type `RequestCode`，it's an int greater than or equal to `0`,you could determine which Activity is turned off based on the returned requestCode in the `OnActivityResult`.

So in the case,have you defined the `REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE` in your activity ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. No I did not define the REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE in my activity. I thought it was some kind of Android constant by the way people were using it. After reading the docs, I don't see where this parameter has anything to do with the (are you sure "Retry" "OK").

Comment: @GaryPg The answer above is for the reason you could not  run.About "Retry" "OK",as you use the standard way of capturing photos in Android which rely on the device actual camera app,the ok/retry functionality is part of the Camera App and we don't have access to it as this will be different between Android "providers" (Samsung, LG, Sony, etc).

Comment: @GaryP One way to avoid this is capturing the photo within your own app using the SurfaceView and not using the camera app.you could refer [this(https://www.airpair.com/android/android-camera-surface-view-fragment) but unfortunately is written in Java but I think it's not too hard to translate into Xamarin/C#.]

Comment: Thank you.  We are currently using the surface view fragment and that is why I am looking at alternatives because fragments have been depreciated.
I will leave it and not change it.

Comment: The second reason is my client would like pinch to zoom and most of the examples using the surface view are vague for Xamarin.